# Extracting recurrent group information from a java Matcher object; Want ALL values inside group, instead of last only

Tags: java, regex

I'm having some problems with a regular expression.. the thing is: consider the following html:

```
<form>
 <input name="methodIndex" value="0" type="hidden">
 <hr align="left" width="80">
 <h4>java.lang.String methodName()</h4>
 <p>Operation exposed for management</p>
 <table border="1" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">
  <tbody>
   <tr class="OperationHeader">
    <th>Param</th>
    <th>ParamType</th>
    <th>ParamValue</th>
    <th>ParamDescription</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>p1</td>
    <td>java.lang.String</td>
    <td><input name="arg0" type="text"></td>
    <td>(no description)</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>p2</td>
    <td>java.lang.String</td>
    <td><input name="arg0" type="text"></td>
    <td>(no description)</td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>
 <input value="Invoke" type="submit">
</form>
```

and now, consider the following regex that formats this html:

```
<input[^>]+name="methodIndex"[^>]*value="(.+?)"[^>]*>
.+?
<h4>\s+\s(.+?)\(\)</h4>
\s+<p>[^<]+</p>
\s*
  (?:<table[^>]+>
    \s*
       <tbody>
         \s*
         <tr[^>]*>(?:\s*<th>[^<]+</th>\s*){4}</tr>
         \s*
         (?:<tr>\s*<td>.+?</td>\s*
                \s*<td>\s*(.+?)\s*</td>\s*
             (?:\s*<td>.+?</td>\s*){2}
            </tr>\s*)+?
         \s*
       </tbody>
    \s*
  </table>)?
.+?
</form>
```

Which I know is way too complex, but hey.. it does the job. Well, kinda... see, it captures all I want to capture, but.. when I have several params (p1, p2, ..., pn), all the params are captured, yet the matcher's group size remains 3.. and group(3) returns the last parameter found - which is pn. C# has a CaptureGroup functionality, but java does not.. how do I capture ALL the values of that recurrent group?

That is my only problem.. finding out a way to capture ALL the values of that group, instead of only the last.

Thank you very much for your help! Hope I've made myself clear...

Comment: Ouch.. Why aren't you using an xml parser for this?

Comment: I don't know. I thought it would be easier (and more direct) using regex.. =/ Maybe I should reconsider the approach? The regex is too complex, I know. =/ *sigh*

Answer (score 0):

It matches everything, but the capture group will only catch what's at the end. Your only option here is to use a regex to eat the first part, then create another to eat and match the params one at a time, then repeatedly call `Matcher.find()` on that part of the input and pull out the param. You can then use another regex to eat the rest of the input. This will be an ugly mess, which is why you should use either a parser generator or an XML parser instead.

Comment: Is there a way to return the subgroup values as a concatenated csv string? Like: "java.lang.String;java.lang.String" for example?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of (though I don't know what you mean by "subgroup values").

Comment: What I mean is: in my case, the java.lang.String is captured twice, because of the pattern, but only the last occurrence is displayed. I'd like to retain all occurrences, if possible.

Comment: No standard library method does that. To get at the subgroup values, you have to turn each into a single group value. That's why I recommend calling `Matcher.find()` in a loop to match each parameter, one at a time, and extract the value of the matching group.

Comment: With C#, you can use CaptureCollection to acquire all the captures by that particular group. That's what I wanted. =/ But I did what you suggested, and transformed it into 2 regexes. Thank you very much. :)